# Error porting Tensorflow Keras model to Tensorflow Version 1.14.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I recently programmed a small NN to play Tic Tac Toe against me.
It really was my first NN I wrote by myself.
Today I wanted to show it to a friend via Google Collab and I got this Error:

```
    model.fit(train_layout, train_place, epochs=3000)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I never got this error before. I think it has to do with Google Collag using Version 1.14.0 and me using Version 1.13.1

Here's my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

model = keras.Sequential([
        keras.layers.Dense(9, activation=tf.nn.tanh),
        keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
        keras.layers.Dense(256, activation=tf.nn.relu),
        keras.layers.Dense(96, activation=tf.nn.relu),
        keras.layers.Dense(9, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
        ])

gd = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.2)

model.compile(gd, loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])


model.fit(train_layout, train_place, epochs=3000)
```

Trainingdata looks like this:

```
train_layout = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
train_place = np.array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

(of course just one data block =D)

Thanks for the help in advance
-nailuj05

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the error, it says `syntax error`, this mostly comes when you have forgotten something in your code to write, like, brackets, commas or sometimes spaces etc. I don't think it is because of the tensorflow versions. I could run this code in colab with TF 1.14 and 1.13, it just showed an error which could be gotten rid by defining the input shape before for the first layer.
for example,

```
model = keras.Sequential([
        keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
        keras.layers.Dense(9, activation=tf.nn.tanh),
        keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
        keras.layers.Dense(256, activation=tf.nn.relu),
        keras.layers.Dense(96, activation=tf.nn.relu),
        keras.layers.Dense(9, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
        ])
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually give yourself an answer.

> I never got this error before. I think it has to do with Google Collag using Version 1.14.0 and me using Version 1.13.1

I think one way to overcome this problem is to save `json` model and manually check the operator names if it's changed in the patches. If your model is `.h5` , I don't know any solution to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

First off,I copy pasted ur code in collab and the error I got was unable to build a dense layer.

Second,Just dumping dense layers of various sizes is not a good idea for such a simple problem of 1 block tic tac toe....i'm sure you will encounter overfitting...

Thridly and the most important one is....you forgot to mention the input layer size...that might be the root cause of the error...